# Confusion about notation in this proof

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I am looking at the following problem from Munkres' topology and a proof previously asked on this forum.

> If $\{\tau_\alpha\}$ is a family of topologies on $X$, show that $\cap \tau_\alpha$ is a topology on $X$.

This was the proof given by a user:

For all $\alpha$, $\varnothing \in \tau_\alpha$ and $X \in \tau_\alpha$. So, $\varnothing \in \cap \{\tau_\alpha\}$ and $X \in \cap \{\tau_\alpha\}$. Now, let $\{U_\beta\}_{\beta \in J}$ be an indexed collection of subsets of $\cap \{\tau_\alpha\}$. Then, for all $\alpha$, $\{U_\beta\}_{\beta \in J} \subseteq \tau_\alpha$. This implies that for all $\alpha$, $\cup\{U_\beta\}_{\beta \in J}\in\tau_\alpha$, since $\tau_\alpha$ is a topology. But then, $\cup\{U_\beta\}_{\beta \in J}\in\cap \{\tau_\alpha\}$.

Now, let $U_1, U_2, \ldots U_n$ be subsets of $\cap \{\tau_\alpha\}$. Then, for all $\alpha$, $U_i \in \tau_\alpha$. This implies that for all $\alpha$, $\cap_{i=1}^n U_i \in \tau_\alpha$, since each $\tau_\alpha$ is a topology. But then, $\cap_{i=1}^n U_i \in \cap \{\tau_\alpha\}$. Therefore, $\cap \{\tau_\alpha\}$ is a topology on $X$.

People told this user the proof was correct, but I am confused on the notation. Wouldn't it be more correct to make the following changes in the proof, or am I confused?

For all $\alpha$, $\varnothing \in \tau_\alpha$ and $X \in \tau_\alpha$. So, $\varnothing \in \cap \tau_\alpha$ and $X \in \cap \tau_\alpha$. Now, let $\{U_\beta\}_{\beta \in J}$ be an indexed collection of elements of $\cap \tau_\alpha$. Then, for all $\alpha$, $\{U_\beta\}_{\beta \in J} \subseteq \tau_\alpha$. This implies that for all $\alpha$, $\cup U_{\beta}$ in$\tau_\alpha$, since $\tau_\alpha$ is a topology. But then, $\cup U_{\beta}\in\cap \tau_{\alpha}$.

Now, let $U_1, U_2, \ldots U_n$ be elements of $\cap \tau_{\alpha}$. Then, for all $\alpha$, $U_i \in \tau_\alpha$. This implies that for all $\alpha$, $\cap_{i=1}^n U_i \in \tau_\alpha$, since each $\tau_\alpha$ is a topology. But then, $\cap_{i=1}^n U_i \in \cap \tau_{\alpha}$. Therefore, $\cap {\tau}_{\alpha}$ is a topology on $X$.

I am mostly confused as to why people giving this user feedback said it was completely correct, I feel like the placement of parenthesis in the unedited proof, make the user's proof very incorrect. Am I right? What is going on here?

Comment: You are right, the set $\{ \tau_\alpha \}$ has to be replaced by $ \tau_\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your point is that the intersection and union of a family of sets should be written as $\cup U_\alpha$ instead of $\cup \{U_\alpha\}$.

The next paragraph is from the ZFC axioms page on wikipedia:

The axiom of union states that for any set of sets $\mathcal{F}$ there is a set $A$ containing every element that is a member of some member of $\mathcal{F}$:

$\forall \mathcal{F} \,\exists A \, \forall Y\, \forall x [(x \in Y \land Y \in \mathcal{F}) \Rightarrow x \in A]$.

That is, you can think of the union as a 'formula' that assigns to a family of sets the union of all the sets in that family. Seen this way, the notation $\cup \{\tau_\alpha;\alpha\in A\}$ makes sense. As in the question they just called the family $\{\tau_\alpha\}$, they also called it this way in the answer, although it would be better to write the index set.

The notation you use is also accepted and more widely used.

Comment: The notation used in the answer is at best very shoddy and in my view so poor as to be incorrect: $\{\tau_\alpha\}$ is a singleton set whose only element is $\tau_\alpha$. I would accept $\bigcap_\alpha\tau_\alpha$, but an index set really ought to be specified: the family is $\{\tau_\alpha:\alpha\in A\}$, and we’re looking at $\bigcap_{\alpha\in A}\tau_\alpha$ or $\bigcap\{\tau_\alpha:\alpha\in A\}$.

Comment: I agree that it would be better to write the indexes, I just didn´t think that was the issue at hand because in his modified answer he doesn´t use indexes either. But I´ll edit the reply to make that clear

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathcal S$ is collection of *sets*, $\bigcap \mathcal S$ is the same as $\bigcap_{A \in \mathcal S} A$. So, in that problem are abusing the notation by writting $\{\tau_\alpha\}$ instead of $\{\tau_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in J}$ for some index set $J$. Thus, in that case $\bigcap \{\tau_\alpha\}$ refers to $\bigcap \{\tau_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in J}$, which is the same as $\bigcap_{\alpha \in J} \tau_\alpha$, as you say.